# Not getting onServiceDisconnected from MarketBillingService

Tags: android, in-app-billing

It seems that I get a resource leak when I try to implement in-app purchase according to the Google Dungeons example.

The problem arises when the MarketbillingService does not call onServiceDisconnected() after a call to unbindService() in the unbind() function (All of which are in the BillingService class).

So my problem is this: How do I release the ServiceConnection to the MarketBillingService?

```
/**
 * This class sends messages to Android Market on behalf of the application by
 * connecting (binding) to the MarketBillingService. The application
 * creates an instance of this class and invokes billing requests through this service.
 *
 * The {@link BillingReceiver} class starts this service to process commands
 * that it receives from Android Market.
 *
 * You should modify and obfuscate this code before using it.
 */
public class BillingService extends Service implements ServiceConnection {

 [...]

/**
 * Unbinds from the MarketBillingService. Call this when the application
 * terminates to avoid leaking a ServiceConnection.
 */
public void unbind() {
    try {
        unbindService(this);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // This might happen if the service was disconnected
    }
}


/**
 * This is called when we are disconnected from the MarketBillingService.
 */
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Billing service disconnected");
    mService = null;
}
```